# FreeBSD pkg init by script

Tags: freebsd

On just installed Freebsd need to initialize `pkg` by hands. Otherwise pkg system not allowed.
How to init `pkg` automatically by script? Maybe need install someone port? Or something else?

Comment: What version did you just install ? For FreeBSD 10.0, the pkg bootstrapping should be (almost) automatic. For former releases, you just set your `make.conf`, get the "pkg" package first and doing the `pkg2ng`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to record a solution, works on 9.3

```
env ASSUME_ALWAYS_YES=YES pkg bootstrap
```

source: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/pkg-unattended-install.36183/#post-245486

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps the simplest solution:

```
# pkg bootstrap -y
```